# CSS:Spinner overwrite the original spinner's settings, need different css setting for each spinner

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I have two type of spinner in ionic 1 framework. The ionic spinner originally has the dark background. Therefore, I turn it off with the code below.

app.js

```
.constant('$ionicLoadingConfig', {
    noBackdrop: true,
    //duration: 1800,
    animation: 'fade-in',
    template: '<ion-spinner icon="crescent" class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner>',

})
```

app.css

```
.loading{
  background-color:transparent!important;
}
```

However, I need a page with a different from others spinner. Only for the page `special.js` where I want the spinner with the original dark background. However, with the code I set, the spinner setting at `app.js` is overwrite.

special.js

```
        $scope.$on("$ionicView.afterEnter",
            function (event, data) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    noBackdrop: true, duration: 1888,
                    template: '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner> <br/>Analyzing'

                });
                $scope.watchLists = $watcherFactory.getWatchLists();
                $scope.currentWatchList = window.localStorage.getItem('currentWatchList');
                console.log($scope.currentWatchList);
                if ($scope.watchLists.length > 0)
                    $scope.getWatchedStocks();
                else {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.currentWatchList = "_";
                }
```

special.css

```
.loading{
  background-color:black!important;
}
```

How to make the spinner in special.css limited to that page only and not overwrite all the spinner?

Currently, background is set to black for all spinner

The spinner that I wanted when app.js loading is (orange color, it is not that obvious)
[image]

The spinner that I wanted when special.js loading is
[image]

Note that in the mobile app, user will jump from page to another page and I just want the special.js page to have the spinner with dark background. app.js spinner is consider the default spinner in the app except when special.js is called.

Update:(kite.js.org)

app.css

```
.loading {
    background-color:transparent!important;
}
.special-page .loading {
    background-color:black!important;
}
```

special.js

```
    $rootScope.isSpecial = true; 
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() 
               {delete $rootScope.isSpecial});



    $scope.$on("$ionicView.afterEnter",
        function (event, data) {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                noBackdrop: true, duration: 1888,
                template: '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner> <br/>Analyzing'

            });
            $scope.watchLists = $watcherFactory.getWatchLists();
            $scope.currentWatchList = window.localStorage.getItem('currentWatchList');
            console.log($scope.currentWatchList);
            if ($scope.watchLists.length > 0)
                $scope.getWatchedStocks();
            else {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.currentWatchList = "_";
            }



        }
    );
```

The default spinner shows transparent background but the spcial.js still show tansparent background instead of black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ionicLoading` appends `div.loading-container` to `<body>`, I can not simply use a single selector to control it over different pages; therefore the problem becomes how I can change `<body>`'s class when special page is entered, my solution is not elegant, but suppose to work:

- add a ngClass to body: `<body ng-class="{'special-page': isSpecialPage}">`, it will be triggered when `isSpecialPage` is true
- inject `$rootScope` for the controller of special.js, and:

  - put `$rootScope.isSpecialPage = true` at the beginning of controller, so `<body>` will have a `special-page` class when this page (ui state) is entered
  - listen to `$destroy` event, change `$rootScope.isSpecialPage = false`, so `special-page` is removed when scope is destroyed (state changed)

> ```
> $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
>     $rootScope.isSpecialPage = false;
> });
> ```

- now you can write css like:

> ```
> .loading {
>     background-color:transparent!important;
> }
> .special-page .loading {
>     background-color:black!important;
> }
> ```

---

Add minimal sample:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $rootScope) {

  function showLoading() {
    // Setup the loader
    $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Loading',
      animation: 'fade-in',
      showBackdrop: true,
      maxWidth: 200,
      showDelay: 0
    });

    $timeout(function () {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $scope.msg = 'content loaded ' + new Date();
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  $scope.showLoading = function(isSpecial) {
    $rootScope.isSpecial = isSpecial;
    showLoading();
  }
});
```

```css
.loading {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.special-page .loading {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 
    
    <title>Ionic Modal</title>

    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-class="{'special-page': isSpecial}">
    
      <ion-view title="Home">
        <ion-header-bar>
          <h1 class="title">Sample Ionic Loading</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content has-header="true">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-click="showLoading();">Click to show transparent Loading</ion-item>
            <ion-item ng-click="showLoading(true);">Click to show special Loading</ion-item>
            <ion-item ng-if="msg">{{msg}}</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not working. is the `<body ng-class="{'special-page': isSpecialPage}"></body>` in html? Also, the css code is in app.css or special.css?

Comment: Yes, modify your top level html page and add `ng-class="{'special-page': isSpecialPage}"` to `<body>` tag, after this you must confirm `special-page` is added / removed to `<body>` when "special page" is entered ( use chrome or firefox dev tool ), after `special-page` is added to `<body>` tag, it does not matter which file contains `.special-page .loading` if every CSS file is loaded in "special page".

Comment: Thanks. I have problem to modified your code to mine for the js part. How to modified the `  $scope.showLoading = function(isSpecial) {
    $rootScope.isSpecial = isSpecial;
    showLoading();
  }` into special.js? Can you show in the answer?

Comment: Well, my code just demonstrated how you can manipulate the "class" of `<body>`, actually you do not need `$scope.showLoading = function(isSpecial) { $rootScope.isSpecial = isSpecial; showLoading(); }`, you should add `$rootScope.isSpecial = true; $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {delete $rootScope.isSpecial;})` before `$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterEnter" ...)`  (your "special.js"), and if `ng-class="{'special-page': isSpecialPage}"` is added to `<body>` tag you may see the "'special-page" is applied / removed to body element after "special page" is entered / exited, that's all you need in JS.

Comment: Thanks. I updated your solution as Update. I am not sure if my updated code is exactly correct. However, it does not sows black background on special.js but keep showing transparent background

Comment: ok, now please use dev tool to check there is no error on this "special.js" and `special-page` class is applied to '<body>', and confirm `.loading {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.special-page .loading {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}` is added to your css file and loaded.

Comment: if `ng-class="{'special-page': isSpecialPage}"` is applied to `<body>` and new "special.js" is evaluated correctly, body element is suppose to  have a `special-page`, if not please post your "index.html" or some other related top level html source.

Comment: There is no errors when `.loading { background-color: transparent !important; } .special-page .loading { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important; }` or in `special.js` page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160168/discussion-between-bkcollection-and-kite-js-org).

Answer (score 0):

What have you done so far is right. You can remove the original spinner again or make it to what you want when you leave the special.js page,

```
//in your special.js controller
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
         //your custom spinner here
});
```

Usefull links,

1. if using state provider - [$stateChangeStart](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)
2. if using location provider - [$locationChangeStart](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#event-$locationChangeStart)

why css matters? you can set the css again to transparent in each page?

Comment: Could you be more specific to the questions? I don't really understand your statement. Please elaborate more. The code is for special.js?

Comment: yes code is for special.js controller. why css matters? you can change the css in each page? if this is not satisfying can you really make a sample app?

Comment: How to put `$ionicLoading.show({noBackdrop: true, duration: 1888,
   template: '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner> <br/>Loading',

});` into stateChangeStart function?

Comment: //like this? is there any error? 
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
         $ionicLoading.show({noBackdrop: true, duration: 1888, template: '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner> <br/>Loading', });
});

Comment: I think I should post more of the code. Please refer the updated post. I already has the `$scope.$on` in my original code. SO additional yours will not work.

Comment: you can write another $scope.$on. just try it. you are wasting time here if you don't try

Comment: Of course I have try, the issues is the code break after adding another $scope.$on.

Comment: I have tried 2 $scope.$on with console.logs it doesn't break and works fine. maybe something in your code? what does it say?

Comment: sorry, my mistake as I omitted });. However, I still unable to get two different spinner background. Can you guide me how you manage to get different spinner background? app.js spinner will be loaded across the app but a special spinner loaded only in special.js with a dark background. Please elaborate more  in the answer

Comment: yeah can help but it will be much easier if you can reproduce using something like plnker. Can you?

Comment: I try to create plunkr by copy my current code in but it does not working. However, the spinner is by default set as app.js except when special.js is loading. The key is background not the spinner itself. The background is set by css as shown above thatt unable to changed between two colors. Spiner itself is able to changed as the question stated above. Hope you understand my meaning. Thanks